# Exported App Engine logs in BigQuery has missing fields

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-logging

For App Engine (Python, Standard environment), I have created a log-export (v2) in the same project as the app. Destination of the sink is a dataset in Google BigQuery.

I can perform some simple queries in BigQuery:

```
SELECT
    severity,
    timestamp AS Time,
    protoPayload.host AS Host,
    protoPayload.status AS Status,
    protoPayload.resource AS Path,
    httpRequest.status,
    httpRequest.requestMethod,
    httpRequest.userAgent,
    httpRequest.remoteIp
FROM
    [MY_PROJECT:MYLOGS.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20170214]
LIMIT
    10
```

While `httpRequest.status` will be shown in the results with values (and the same for all the other selected fields), other fields of `httpRequest` are shown with `null`, e.g.: `requestMethod`, `userAgent`, `remoteIp`.

On the Cloud Log web page, I can see these log entries and these values are existing, but it seems that they are not exported to BigQuery.

When I try to filter by the request method to be `GET`, e.g.:

```
SELECT
    severity,
    timestamp AS Time,
    protoPayload.host AS Host,
    protoPayload.status AS Status,
    protoPayload.resource AS Path,
    httpRequest.status,
    httpRequest.requestMethod,
    httpRequest.userAgent,
    httpRequest.remoteIp
FROM
    [MY_PROJECT:MYLOGS.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20170214]
WHERE
    httpRequest.requestMethod = 'GET'
LIMIT
    10
```

This query will return zero records.

Any idea, why some fields are not shown in queries and cannot be used for filters in BigQuery?

Comment: Does this happen on previous days data too?

Comment: I don't know. It's the first date I have exported the logs and first time using BigQuery. Do you think future exports may include these fields?

Comment: @Pentium10 I've tried the same query with the data of the next two days and I have the same issue.

Comment: I've found equivalent fields in protoPayload, and those values exist:

    protoPayload.method
    protoPayload.userAgent
    protoPayload.ip AS RemoteIP

Not sure about the technical reasons, but at least the documentation makes more sense to me now, and I can work with it.